# Rails 2.3.x: is there render_to_string replacement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, render, partial

`render_to_string` is deprecated but there is no replacement mentioned in the API docs. How can you render a partial to a string in a controller without using this function? I need this to do things like this:

```
render :update do |page|
    ...
    page.call "Lightbox.create", render_to_string(:partial => "...", ...)
end
```

Or:

```
render :json => {
    ...,
    :message => render_to_string(:partial => "...", ...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`render :partial => "..."` should return the rendered partial (unlike render "a_view").

Answer (score 0):

[render_to_string](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render_to_string) method has been moved to the [ActionController::Rendering](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Rendering) module.

Here is the render_to_string [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.3/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb#L20)

Try to call `render_to_string` on `ActionController::Base` like so:

`ActionController::Base.new.render_to_string ...`